# Synchronous AJAX call

Tags: ajax, synchronous

In a scenario, I have written a javascript and in middle of the script I made an AJAX call. There is some more amount of script which is present after the AJAX call and this needs to be executed based on the results returned from the function. But Unfortunately the script which is present after the AJAX call is executed before the function call itself, that is, the call is being made asynchronously. Could anyone please suggest me how to overcome this problem?

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: Use callbacks or promises.  Do not freeze the user's browser.

Comment: It is always helpful to include sample code when asking questions. [ask]

Comment: ya sure...and I have seen the syntax of callbacks and promises and tried to execute them. But there were some errors in the program I did. Also I was confused where to use them in my scenario

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Are you using jQuery? IF not, you should :)
Then you should read this documentation - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
And put the rest of the script in the success handler of the ajax function.

If you still insist on not using jQuery, just use the onreadystatechange function
http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_onreadystatechange.asp

Comment: Could you please elaborate? Do you mean to say that I need to nest my function inside success? Sorry to trouble you because I am newbie

Comment: Yes, you need to nest your function inside success. See the link I sent.

Comment: Ya I will try and let you know if I face any trouble. Thanks for Quick response

Comment: Ya sure.. Could you please let me know whether there is any mistake or not here?     function load()
{
alert("1");
alert("2");
$.ajax({async:false,
   beforeSend: function(){
     setTimeout(function(){alert("beforeSend")},3000); // Here goes my appian function and time can't be predicted
   },
   success: function(){
     alert("success");
   }
 });
alert("4");
} But still the call is asynchronous. I have to embed jquery inside js as shown in above manner and after the execution of function (with result obtained) only the remaining script should run.

Comment: There were some mistakes, I've made some corrections here - http://jsfiddle.net/SdqtK/

Comment: Thanks for your patience, It was of great help to me.